# Probabilities of royal flush

Tags: probability-theory

The probability of a royal flush in a poker hand is p = 1/649,740. How large
must n be to render the probability of having no royal flush in n hands smaller
than 1/e?

Comment: Why do you post questions with no context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of no royal flush in one hand is: $$1 - \dfrac1{649740} = \frac{649739}{649740}$$

Assuming independence of the hands, the probability of no royal flush in $n$ hands is:
$$\left(\frac{649739}{649740}\right)^n$$

So we want $n$ such that $$ \left(\frac{649739}{649740}\right)^n < \frac1e.$$

Start by taking the natural log of both sides:
$$n \ln\left(\frac{649739}{649740}\right) < - 1$$

Can you take it from here?  Caution/hint:  The natural log on the left-hand side is a negative value.